# HTML - tide times - change source url based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

**Why**:
My site will have tide times as a small feature (so not the primary feature).

**What**:
As part of that tide times feature, I want to provide the user a 'drop down' set of options to select a location and the default tide times update with the users selection.

**Why it's not working**:
After selecting an option, the table disappears. It should not disappear. It should update with the chosen location.

Would love some help/direction on this.  **It's been driving me crazy for the past week now.**

**Long summary:**
I'm bolting together the site and I have a tide time widget / html snippet. Only the snippet doesn't come with the option for a user to change the location. I hope to customise the html page to include a drop down list and the selected value replace the src url location. Then the widget updates on the change (not the whole page).

I've been learning lots on here. But I am a novice - so maybe there are basic rules I am breaking.

Would love some help/direction on this. It's been driving me crazy for the past week now.

I've been researching and the code below is what I came up with.

```
<select onChange="ChangeLocation(value)">
  <option value="-">Select region</option>
  <option value="barry">Barry</option>
  <option value="aldeburgh">Aldeburgh</option>
</select>

 
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function ChangeLocation(value)
      {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";
          s.src = "https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/" + value + "-tide-times.js";
          s.id = "tidetable";
          s.async = true;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("output").appendChild(s);
         
      }
  </script>
  
  
<div id="output">
    <script id="tidetable" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/aldeburgh-tide-times.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the website url so we can have look

Comment: I can't I'm afraid. It's in such bad shape with ideas and concepts all over the place... That feature is only a small part of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using "postscribe" from https://github.com/krux/postscribe.

I'm using postscribe from the cdn by using it in the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/postscribe/2.0.8/postscribe.min.js"></script>
```

Then, the content of the `<body>` tag as following:

```
<select onChange="ChangeLocation(value)">
    <option value="-">Select region</option>
    <option value="barry">Barry</option>
    <option value="aldeburgh">Aldeburgh</option>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeLocation(value) {

        var s = document.createElement("script");

        s.src = "https://www.tidetimes.org.uk/" + value + "-tide-times.js";

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

        postscribe('#output', s.outerHTML);

    }
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).